# Как найти периодические события в серии времён?

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение

Есть серия timestamp'ов. Большинство из них ложатся на периодическую сетку. **Но:**

1. не все – могут быть выпадающие из сетки сэмплы (их допустимый процент - задаётся;
2. не всегда подряд на каждое значение сетки (процент пропусков - задаётся);
3. не идеально точно – допустимо небольшое отклонение (задаётся).

**Задача: найти период сетки.** Наверное, могут быть случаи, когда несколько вариантов периода сеток - тогда выбираем охвативший наибольшее число сэмплов, с наибольшим периодом. А может случиться, и что с заданными параметрами решение отсутствует.

Пример. Серия с периодом (который в задаче надо найти) = 30, в секундах:

```
10, 40, 72, 99, 164, 172, 190
```

Отклонения в +/- 4 секунды считаем допустимыми. Пропуск шага 130 – ок. Всего одно «лишнее» значение 172, не вписывающееся в ряд – тоже ок.

Можно было бы считать шагом сетки 10, или вообще 1, но это мелко : ) Чем больше шаг – тем «лучше». *Это мы уже о ф-ии качества говорим?*

**Каким способом искать решение?** Не могу сообразить, как подступиться. Задача именно для небольших наборов данных. Никаких bigdata.

**Upd.** Поиск наибольшего общего делителя с допустимой погрешностью – можно ещё так сформулировать мою задачу.

Comment: Небольшой набор данных - сколько в нем значений?

Comment: Варьируется, ориентировочно до 1e4

Comment: По моему вам надо копать в сторону корреляционного анализа.

Comment: Основная масса событий укладывается в период (+/-) или может быть ситуация, когда половина событий почти  периодическая, а остальные случайно разбросаны? Или есть несколько последовательностей с разным периодом, которые   наложены друг на друга. Вообще-то, если намекнете на "физическую сущность" данных, то может будет проще придумать нечто адекватное.

Comment: Данные – абсолютный хаос, введённый людьми. Смысл приложения – искать в их событиях закономерности, если они вообще есть. Напр. если больше K1 % сэмплов укладывается в какую-то сетку, можно считать, что законмерность есть. Могут найтись несколько последовательностей с разными периодами – брать самые "весомые" из них. Ф-я веса – от % сэмплов, попадающих в нее, допущенных отклонений и кол-ва "дырок".

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, почему все числа монотонно возрастают.

Comment: @avp это ,по замыслу, unix timestamp'ы, когда у одного человека происходили события одного типа. Вводит их он сам, вручную. Отсюда неточность, до суток. Цифры примера для иллюстрации, упрощенно.

Answer (score 4):

Приведён небольшой массив данных, который в рамках задачи требуется аппроксимировать линейной функцией.
По [методу наименьших квадратов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) для зависимости **y<sub>i</sub> = a x<sub>i</sub> + b** нетрудно получить СЛАУ вида
**s<sub>2</sub>a + s<sub>1</sub>b = r<sub>1</sub>,**
**s<sub>1</sub>a + s<sub>0</sub>b = r<sub>0</sub>,**
где
**s<sub>0</sub> = sum(i<sup>0</sup>) = n,**
**s<sub>1</sub> = sum(i<sup>1</sup>) = n(n-1)/2,**
**s<sub>2</sub> = sum(i<sup>2</sup>) = n(n-1)(2n-1)/6,**
**r<sub>0</sub> = sum(i<sup>0</sup>x<sub>i</sub>) = sum(x<sub>i</sub>),**
**r<sub>0</sub> = sum(i<sup>1</sup>x<sub>i</sub>) = sum(ix<sub>i</sub>),**
решение которой элементарно.

Программа:

```
$issue = [10, 40, 72, 99, 164, 172, 190];

function line($arr){
    $r0 = array_sum($arr);
    $r1 = 0;
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
        $r1 += $key*$item;
    }
    $s0 = count($arr);
    $s1 = $s0*($s0-1)/2;
    $s2 = $s1*(2*$s0-1)/3;
    $delta = $s0*$s2 - $s1*$s1;
    $delta1 = $s0*$r1 - $s1*$r0;
    $delta2 = $s2*$r0 - $s1*$r1;
    $a = $delta1/$delta;
    $b = $delta2/$delta;
    return [$a, $b];
}
list($a, $b) = line($issue);
printf("y = %.3f x + %.3f b", $a, $b);
```

Результат:

```
y = 32.000 x + 10.714 b
```

Comment: Спасибо за лаконичное решение! Как я понимаю, «выпадающее» из канвы занчение сэмпла 172 здесь не игнорируется, а влияет на результат?

Comment: @Sergics Да, конечно. При таком количестве данных отбрасывание точек - непозволительная роскошь.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы попробовал как-то так.

1. Отсортируем значения, подсчитаем их последовательные разности. (Разности нужны, чтобы от сетки вида `aT + b` перейти к сетке вида `T`. Например идеальные тестовые данные `5, 25, 45, 65` превратятся в `20, 20, 20, 20`). Получаем в нашем случае:

   ```
   10, 40, 72, 99, 152, 164, 190
   30, 32, 27, 53,  12,  26
   ```
2. Предполагаем, что большинство соседних разностей находятся в окрестности «истинного» значения периода. Кластеризуем полученные разности. Для этого установим величину *r*, и объединим в группы разности по следующему принципу:

   - Сначала список групп пуст. Обходим список чисел по одному.
   - Для очередного числа, будем считать, что оно попадает в группу с точностью *r*, если оно находится на расстоянии не больше *r* от хотя бы одного числа этой группы.
   - Если число не попало ни в одну группу, оно начинает новую группу.
   - Если число попало только в одну группу, оно к ней присоединяется.
   - Если число попало в несколько групп, эти группы и число сливаются в одну группу.
3. В конце должна получиться одна группа, содержащая, скажем, больше половины всех чисел. Если в наибольшей группе слишком много чисел, уменьшаем *r* вдвое и повторяем. Если слишком мало, увеличиваем вдвое и повторяем. Для нашего случая:

   - *r* = 1: каждое число — отдельный кластер, увеличиваем *r*
   - *r* = 2: кластеры `[12], [26, 27], [30, 32], [52]`, увеличиваем *r*
   - *r* = 4: кластеры `[12], [26, 27, 30, 32], [52]`. Нашли.
4. Среднее арифметическое наибольшей группы и есть приближение к шагу. В нашем случае, 28.75
5. Далее, пробуем уточнить оценку, расставляя числа в решётке. Пусть истинный период T, мы знаем, что T ≈ 28.75. Начнём с какого-нибудь из чисел, сформировавших «большинство». Например, 26 — член большинства, получилось из 190 и 164, начинаем от 164.

   - следующее число 190, разность 26. Записываем: T ≈ 26
   - предыдущее число 152, разность 12, поскольку она слишком далека от целого числа периодов (12/T ≈ 12/28.75 ≈ 0.41), выбрасываем это число из рассмотрения, оно «постороннее».
   - предыдущее число 99, разность 65. 65/28.75 ≈ 2.25, считаем, что 99 лежит на сетке, записываем: 2T ≈ 65, T ≈ 32,5
   - предыдущее число 72, разность 27, делим на предполагаемый период, получаем 0.93, ложится на сетку. Записываем T ≈ 27
   - аналогично получаем следующие оценки T ≈ 32 и T ≈ 30

   Усредняем полученные приближения, получаем немного более хорошее приближение 29.5.

---

В принципе, есть другие, более продвинуты методы кластеризации. (Но я их не знаю, лишь слыхал о них.) Например, на Хабре есть [статья одного из наших постоянных участников](http://habrahabr.ru/post/101338/).

Comment: Прошу прощения за опечатку в примере данных: они конечно же идут по возрастанию, вместо 152 хотел написать 172. 

Решение понял. С приведёнными данными оно находит правильный ответ. Его сбивает с толку число-аутсайдер, и не позволяет оценить кратный интервал `99–164 ~= 2*30`. Мне кажется, придётся проверять все возможные комбинации, проваливаясь в NP-полноту.

Comment: @Sergiks: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Похоже, это сработает! Во всяком случае на относительно явных наборах, где шума из аутсайдеров и дырок немного. Ещё раздумываю над применением преобразования Фурье.

Comment: @Sergiks: По идее, можно оценивать качество приближения как среднеквадратичное отклонение каждого члена последовательнсти разностей от ближайшего кратного периоду. Но я не уверен в качестве этой оценки, надо повторить курс статистики.

Comment: @Sergiks: Один мой знакомый, использовал преобразование Фурье, чтобы получить частотный спектр звука, и при помощи похожих идей искал в нём ноты.